# get my cursor from sum function

Tags: android, cursor, adapter, textview

This is my function to get the query :

```
public Cursor getSaldo(String id) {
        String[] args={id};
        return(getReadableDatabase()
        .rawQuery("SELECT sum("+t_jumlah+") "+
                "as "+t_saldo+" "+
                "FROM "+t_table+" WHERE "+t_nId+"=?", args));
```

What can I do to put the data in my `TextView`?

I have cursor like this

```
almagId=getIntent().getStringExtra(Nasabah.ID_EXTRA);

Cursor c=helper.getSaldo(almagId);
startManagingCursor(c);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may do something like this . Just give a try

```
 if(!cursor.moveToFirst()){
 mytextView.setText("No output");
}
else{
do {
mytextView.setText(cursor.getString(0)); 

} while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

Comment: Alhamdulillah it work to put data in my textview. thanks a lot.